# charAt() unable to extract individual members with array

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have one array which is a fixed array.
I have assigned some strings to it when it is created like:

```
String []alpha = new String[]{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q"};
```

But it is giving me an error for this line:

```
alpha.charAt(0); //error
```

I have also tried this with dynamic arrays where user is entering a string and I access the string with a userText variable:

```
userText.charAt(i); //valid
```

Is this correct? I am not getting an error.

Comment: An array doesn't *have* a `charAt()` method. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html for how arrays work in Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alpha.charAt(0);
```

`alpha` is array, so you need to use index for lookup to get `String` and then get first character.

Example:

```
alpha[0].chartAt(0);
```

Note: This is example only, make sure `length` and `null` checks are performed when you do index lookup.

There is not enough code in your question, but I guess `userText.chartAt(i)` not giving error because `userText` is `String`.

Comment: let me check using alpha[0].chartAt(0);